# Проблема с позиционированием

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
  <style>
    .calendar {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .calendar-header {
      display: table-row-group;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .calendar-header .day {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      width: 146px;
      max-width: 146px;
    }
    
    .calendar-body {
      display: table-row-group;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .calendar-body .day:nth-child(1),
    .calendar-header .day:nth-child(1) {
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    .calendar-body .day {
      display: table-cell;
      position: relative;
      border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 0 2px;
      max-width: 146px;
    }
    
    .calendar-week-container {
      display: table-row;
      min-height: 4em;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0;
      height: 141px;
    }
    
    .fc-day-grid-event {
      background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
      border-bottom-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-image-outset: 0px;
      border-image-repeat: stretch;
      border-image-slice: 100%;
      border-image-source: none;
      border-image-width: 1;
      border-left-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
      border-left-style: solid;
      border-left-width: 1px;
      border-right-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-right-width: 1px;
      border-top-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-top-width: 1px;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      cursor: pointer;
      direction: ltr;
      display: block;
      font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 11.05px;
      font-weight: 400;
      height: 14px;
      line-height: 14.365px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      margin-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      padding-left: 6px;
      padding-right: 6px;
      padding-top: 4px;
      text-align: left;
      text-decoration-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      text-decoration-line: none;
      text-decoration-style: solid;
      text-size-adjust: 100%;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    .fc-day-grid-event .fc.content {
      border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
      border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
      border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
      box-sizing: content-box;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      cursor: pointer;
      direction: ltr;
      display: block;
      font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 11.05px;
      font-weight: 400;
      height: 14px;
      line-height: 14.365px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      position: relative;
      text-align: left;
      text-size-adjust: 100%;
      user-select: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 128px;
      z-index: 2;
      -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: black;
    }
    
    .fc-day-grid-event .fc.content .fc-title {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      cursor: pointer;
      direction: ltr;
      display: inline;
      font-family: "open sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 11.05px;
      font-weight: 400;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 14.365px;
      text-align: left;
      text-size-adjust: 100%;
      user-select: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: auto;
      -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
  </style>
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendar-header">
      <div class="day">
        Sun
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Mon
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Tue
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Wed
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Thu
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Fri
      </div>
      <div class="day">
        Sat
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-body">

      <div class="calendar-week-container">
        <div class="day empty"></div>
        <div class="day empty"></div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-01"><span class="dayNumber">1</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-02"><span class="dayNumber">2</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-03"><span class="dayNumber">3</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-04"><span class="dayNumber">4</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-05"><span class="dayNumber">5</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-week-container">
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-06"><span class="dayNumber">6</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-07"><span class="dayNumber">7</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38717" data-sort="0" data-program="1" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="36" style="background-color: rgb(26, 123, 185); border-color: rgb(26, 123, 185);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">Bridge: Oppo Day</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-08"><span class="dayNumber">8</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-09"><span class="dayNumber">9</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-10"><span class="dayNumber">10</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38723" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="223" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">Mound Blending A</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-11"><span class="dayNumber">11</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38724" data-sort="0" data-program="3" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="251" style="background-color: rgb(248, 172, 89); border-color: rgb(248, 172, 89);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">Upper Strength</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-12"><span class="dayNumber">12</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-week-container">
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-13"><span class="dayNumber">13</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-14"><span class="dayNumber">14</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38725" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="223" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); width: 912px;">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">Mound Blending A</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38726" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="231" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">VeloDay 6oz-4oz</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38727" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="237" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">HybridA</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-15"><span class="dayNumber">15</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38728" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="223" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">Mound Blending A</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-16"><span class="dayNumber">16</span>
          <div class="events">
            <div>
              <a class="fc-day-grid-event" data-id="38729" data-sort="0" data-program="0" data-editable="1" data-workout-id="226" style="background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">
                <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-title">X2-LiveABs</span></div>
                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-17"><span class="dayNumber">17</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-18"><span class="dayNumber">18</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-19"><span class="dayNumber">19</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-week-container">
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-20"><span class="dayNumber">20</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-21"><span class="dayNumber">21</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-22"><span class="dayNumber">22</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-23"><span class="dayNumber">23</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-24"><span class="dayNumber">24</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-25"><span class="dayNumber">25</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-26"><span class="dayNumber">26</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-week-container">
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-27"><span class="dayNumber">27</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-28"><span class="dayNumber">28</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-29"><span class="dayNumber">29</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-30"><span class="dayNumber">30</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day" data-date="2018-05-31"><span class="dayNumber">31</span>
          <div class="events"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="day empty"></div>
        <div class="day empty"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

На 14 дате есть растянутые событие до 17 числа, но на 15 и 16 есть тоже события, как сделать так чтобы эти события опускались ниже?
`absolute` позиционирование естестевенно не поможет, табличную верстку я не хочу, так как требуется сделать сортировку между событиями в дне

Comment: Ничего не понял, куда ниже, они же в своем столбце. Вопрос не понятный.  Может вам нужен `vertical-align:bottom;` ?  Пожалуйста, опишите более подробно, что вы хотите.

Comment: почему не сделать это всё flex-ами внутри див-ячеек и раскладывай как хочешь, родитель будет их держать не выпуская за границы. и почему box-sizing не border-box?